# HUAWEI Mate20 webrtc crash issue:Failed to set remote answer sdp: Failed to set remote video description send parameters

Tags: java, android, webrtc

I'm working on adding native AWS webrtc for our Android hybrid App. It works well on other smartphones but will crash on HUAWEI. When the webrtc connection succeed, App crashed. Here is the part of the Log:

```
    D/webRTC: sent sdp offer
D/KinesisVideoSdpObserver: onCreateSuccess(): SDP=v=0
    o=- 4089128915904689992 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
    s=-
    t=0 0
    a=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2
    a=msid-semantic: WMS KvsLocalMediaStream
    m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 127
    c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=ice-ufrag:EmPX
    a=ice-pwd:m5FQR9O6Gu+m0kQk8SFYXUg6
    a=ice-options:trickle renomination
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 71:6C:44:F7:66:58:E0:BE:C9:CB:0E:E7:54:0C:2A:05:9B:AC:B1:A8:27:60:CC:A4:CE:A7:50:D7:45:41:94:7E
    a=setup:actpass
    a=mid:0
    a=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
    a=extmap:13 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
    a=extmap:12 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
    a=extmap:2 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
    a=extmap:11 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
    a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
    a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
    a=extmap:8 http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-avtext-framemarking-07
    a=extmap:9 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space
    a=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
    a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
    a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
    a=sendrecv
    a=msid:KvsLocalMediaStream KvsVideoTrack
    a=rtcp-mux
    a=rtcp-rsize
    a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
    a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
    a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
    a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
    a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
    a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:97 apt=96
    a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
    a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
    a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
    a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
    a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
    a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:99 apt=98
    a=rtpmap:100 red/90000
    a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:101 apt=100
    a=rtpmap:127 ulpfec/90000
    a=ssrc-group:FID 3389218480 1760322665
    a=ssrc:3389218480 cname:oMzbiO27u3BctYUf
    a=ssrc:3389218480 msid:KvsLocalMediaStream KvsVideoTrack
    a=ssrc:3389218480 mslabel:KvsLocalMediaStream
    a=ssrc:3389218480 label:KvsVideoTrack
    a=ssrc:1760322665 cname:oMzbiO27u3BctYUf
    a=ssrc:1760322665 msid:KvsLocalMediaStream KvsVideoTrack
    a=ssrc:1760322665 mslabel:KvsLocalMediaStream
    a=ssrc:1760322665 label:KvsVideoTrack
    m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
    c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=ice-ufrag:EmPX
    a=ice-pwd:m5FQR9O6Gu+m0kQk8SFYXUg6
    a=ice-options:trickle renomination
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 71:6C:44:F7:66:58:E0:BE:C9:CB:0E:E7:54:0C:2A:05:9B:AC:B1:A8:27:60:CC:A4:CE:A7:50:D7:45:41:94:7E
    a=setup:actpass
    a=mid:1
    a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
    a=extmap:2 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
    a=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
    a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
    a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
    a=recvonly
    a=rtcp-mux
    a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
    a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
    a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
    a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
    a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
    a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
    a=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000
    a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
    a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
    a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
    a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
    a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
    a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
    a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
    a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
    a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
    m=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel
    c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=ice-ufrag:EmPX
    a=ice-pwd:m5FQR9O6Gu+m0kQk8SFYXUg6
    a=ice-options:trickle renomination
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 71:6C:44:F7:66:58:E0:BE:C9:CB:0E:E7:54:0C:2A:05:9B:AC:B1:A8:27:60:CC:A4:CE:A7:50:D7:45:41:94:7E
    a=setup:actpass
    a=mid:2
    a=sctp-port:5000
    a=max-message-size:262144
D/KVSPeerConnection: onSignalingChange(): signalingState = [HAVE_LOCAL_OFFER]
I/org.webrtc.Logging: NetworkMonitor: Start monitoring with native observer 502242368320
I/Liveview Success Time1: 1649211791701
D/WebSocketClient:  isOpen true
D/SignalingServiceWebSocketClient: Sending Offer
D/KinesisVideoSdpObserver: onSetSuccess(): SDP
D/KVSPeerConnection: onIceGatheringChange(): iceGatheringState = [GATHERING]
I/ice: ================
D/KVSPeerConnection: onIceCandidate(): iceCandidate = [0:0:candidate:1114595702 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.0.110 37983 typ host generation 0 ufrag EmPX network-id 3 network-cost 10:]
D/KVSWebRtcActivity: Sending IceCandidate to remote peer 0:0:candidate:1114595702 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.0.110 37983 typ host generation 0 ufrag EmPX network-id 3 network-cost 10:
D/webRTC: send IceCandidate
D/SignalingServiceWebSocketClient: Sending JSON Message= xxxxxxx
D/SignalingServiceWebSocketClient: Sending JSON Message= xxxxxxx
    Sent Ice candidate message
I/sent icecandidate time: 1649211791772
I/ice: ================
D/KVSPeerConnection: onIceCandidate(): iceCandidate = [0:0:candidate:842163049 1 udp 1686052607 223.112.52.222 37983 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.110 rport 37983 generation 0 ufrag EmPX network-id 3 network-cost 10:stun:52.40.66.127:443]
D/KVSWebRtcActivity: Sending IceCandidate to remote peer 0:0:candidate:842163049 1 udp 1686052607 223.112.52.222 37983 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.110 rport 37983 generation 0 ufrag EmPX network-id 3 network-cost 10:stun:52.40.66.127:443
D/webRTC: send IceCandidate
D/SignalingServiceWebSocketClient: Sending JSON Message= {"action":"ICE_CANDIDATE","messagePayload":"eyJjYW5kaWRhdGUiOiJjYW5kaWRhdGU6ODQyMTYzMDQ5IDEgdWRwIDE2ODYwNTI2MDcgMjIzLjExMi41Mi4yMjIgMzc5ODMgdHlwIHNyZmx4IHJhZGRyIDE5Mi4xNjguMC4xMTAgcnBvcnQgMzc5ODMgZ2VuZXJhdGlvbiAwIHVmcmFnIEVtUFggbmV0d29yay1pZCAzIG5ldHdvcmstY29zdCAxMCIsInNkcE1pZCI6IjAiLCJzZHBNTGluZUluZGV4IjowfQ","senderClientId":"f3338830-084f-4736-bb78-2f56cee638df"}
D/SignalingServiceWebSocketClient: Sent JSON Message= {"action":"ICE_CANDIDATE","messagePayload":"eyJjYW5kaWRhdGUiOiJjYW5kaWRhdGU6ODQyMTYzMDQ5IDEgdWRwIDE2ODYwNTI2MDcgMjIzLjExMi41Mi4yMjIgMzc5ODMgdHlwIHNyZmx4IHJhZGRyIDE5Mi4xNjguMC4xMTAgcnBvcnQgMzc5ODMgZ2VuZXJhdGlvbiAwIHVmcmFnIEVtUFggbmV0d29yay1pZCAzIG5ldHdvcmstY29zdCAxMCIsInNkcE1pZCI6IjAiLCJzZHBNTGluZUluZGV4IjowfQ","senderClientId":"f3338830-084f-4736-bb78-2f56cee638df"}
    Sent Ice candidate message
I/sent icecandidate time: 1649211791991
D/Web Console: scroll refreshed
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "scroll refreshed", source: 
D/CustomMessageHandler: Received message
D/CustomMessageHandler: Received message
D/CustomMessageHandler: Received message
I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: Duration: 4005 ms. Frames received: 0. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 0. Render fps: .0. Average render time: NA. Average swapBuffer time: NA.
I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: Duration: 4008 ms. Frames received: 0. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 0. Render fps: .0. Average render time: NA. Average swapBuffer time: NA.
I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: Duration: 4010 ms. Frames received: 0. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 0. Render fps: .0. Average render time: NA. Average swapBuffer time: NA.
D/CustomMessageHandler: Received message xxxxxx
D/CustomMessageHandler: Answer received: SenderClientId=null
D/KVSWebRtcActivity: SDP answer received from signaling
D/webRTC: SDP answer received from signaling
D/Event: SDP answer received from master:v=0
    o=- 1008569513 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
    s=-
    t=0 0
    a=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2
    a=msid-semantic: WMS myKvsVideoStream
    m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 0
    c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
    a=candidate:3 1 udp 16777215 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000 0 typ relay raddr ::/0 rport 0 generation 0 network-cost 999
    a=candidate:2 1 udp 16777215 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000 0 typ relay raddr ::/0 rport 0 generation 0 network-cost 999
    a=candidate:1 1 udp 1694498815 192.168.100.127 58511 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 network-cost 999
    a=candidate:0 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.100.127 49366 typ host raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 network-cost 999
    a=msid:myKvsVideoStream myVideoTrack
    a=ssrc:1245743577 cname:4/iWRN2u/W8ElBZu
    a=ssrc:1245743577 msid:myKvsVideoStream myVideoTrack
    a=ssrc:1245743577 mslabel:myKvsVideoStream
    a=ssrc:1245743577 label:myVideoTrack
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=ice-ufrag:RRgY
    a=ice-pwd:TeUGFE3L9FpsBOW3dCZSIycZ
    a=ice-options:trickle
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 DC:C5:AE:21:EC:E8:40:70:05:7F:1A:07:5C:F1:FF:64:3F:1B:8D:9F:59:34:C9:7A:B8:F3:EB:BE:D9:68:92:26
    a=setup:active
    a=mid:0
    a=sendrecv
    a=rtcp-mux
    a=rtcp-rsize
    a=rtpmap:0 H264/90000
    a=rtcp-fb:0 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:0 transport-cc
    m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 0
    c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
    a=candidate:3 1 udp 16777215 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000 0 typ relay raddr ::/0 rport 0 generation 0 network-cost 999
    a=candidate:2 1 udp 16777215 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000 0 typ relay raddr ::/0 rport 0 generation 0 network-cost 999
    a=candidate:1 1 udp 1694498815 192.168.100.127 58511 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 network-cost 999
    a=candidate:0 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.100.127 49366 typ host raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 network-cost 999
    a=msid:myKvsAudioStream myAudioTrack
    a=ssrc:1029037518 cname:4/iWRN2u/W8ElBZu
    a=ssrc:1029037518 msid:myKvsAudioStream myAudioTrack
    a=ssrc:1029037518 mslabel:myKvsAudioStream
    a=ssrc:1029037518 label:myAudioTrack
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=ice-ufrag:RRgY
    a=ice-pwd:TeUGFE3L9FpsBOW3dCZSIycZ
    a=ice-options:trickle
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 DC:C5:AE:21:EC:E8:40:70:05:7F:1A:07:5C:F1:FF:64:3F:1B:8D:9F:59:34:C9:7A:B8:F3:EB:BE:D9:68:92:26
    a=setup:active
    a=mid:1
    a=sendonly
    a=rtcp-mux
    a=rtcp-rsize
    a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
    a=rtcp-fb:0 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:0 transport-cc
    m=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel
    c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
    a=candidate:3 1 udp 16777215 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000 0 typ relay raddr ::/0 rport 0 generation 0 network-cost 999
    a=candidate:2 1 udp 16777215 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000 0 typ relay raddr ::/0 rport 0 generation 0 network-cost 999
    a=candidate:1 1 udp 1694498815 192.168.100.127 58511 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 network-cost 999
    a=candidate:0 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.100.127 49366 typ host raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 network-cost 999
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=ice-ufrag:RRgY
    a=ice-pwd:TeUGFE3L9FpsBOW3dCZSIycZ
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 DC:C5:AE:21:EC:E8:40:70:05:7F:1A:07:5C:F1:FF:64:3F:1B:8D:9F:59:34:C9:7A:B8:F3:EB:BE:D9:68:92:26
    a=setup:active
    a=mid:2
    a=sctp-port:5000
I/receive sdpanswer time: 1649211803034
D/KVSPeerConnection: onSignalingChange(): signalingState = [STABLE]
D/KVSWebRtcActivity: Answer Client ID: null
E/KinesisVideoSdpObserver: onSetFailure(): Error=Failed to set remote answer sdp: Failed to set remote video description send parameters.
D/KVSWebRtcActivity: Pending ice candidates found? null
D/CustomMessageHandler: Received message{"messagePayload":"eyJjYW5kaWRhdGUiOiJjYW5kaWRhdGU6MCAxIHVkcCAyMTMwNzA2NDMxIDE5Mi4xNjguMTAwLjEyNyA0OTM2NiB0eXAgaG9zdCByYWRkciAwLjAuMC4wIHJwb3J0IDAgZ2VuZXJhdGlvbiAwIG5ldHdvcmstY29zdCA5OTkiLCJzZHBNaWQiOiIwIiwic2RwTUxpbmVJbmRleCI6MH0=","messageType":"ICE_CANDIDATE"}
D/CustomMessageHandler: Ice Candidate received: SenderClientId=null
    {"candidate":"candidate:0 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.100.127 49366 typ host raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 network-cost 999","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0}
D/KVSWebRtcActivity: Received IceCandidate from remote 
D/KVSWebRtcActivity: Peer connection found already
D/KVSPeerConnection: onIceConnectionChange(): iceConnectionState = [CHECKING]
D/KVSWebRtcActivity: Added ice candidate 0:0:candidate:0 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.100.127 49366 typ host raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 network-cost 999: Successfully
D/CustomMessageHandler: Received message{"messagePayload":"eyJjYW5kaWRhdGUiOiJjYW5kaWRhdGU6MSAxIHVkcCAxNjk0NDk4ODE1IDIyMy4xMTIuNTIuMjIyIDU4NTExIHR5cCBzcmZseCByYWRkciAwLjAuMC4wIHJwb3J0IDAgZ2VuZXJhdGlvbiAwIG5ldHdvcmstY29zdCA5OTkiLCJzZHBNaWQiOiIwIiwic2RwTUxpbmVJbmRleCI6MH0=","messageType":"ICE_CANDIDATE"}
D/CustomMessageHandler: Ice Candidate received: SenderClientId=null
D/CustomMessageHandler: {"candidate":"candidate:1 1 udp 1694498815 223.112.52.222 58511 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 network-cost 999","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0}
D/KVSWebRtcActivity: Received IceCandidate from remote 
D/KVSWebRtcActivity: Peer connection found already
D/KVSWebRtcActivity: Added ice candidate 0:0:candidate:1 1 udp 1694498815 223.112.52.222 58511 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 network-cost 999: Successfully
D/KVSPeerConnection: onIceConnectionChange(): iceConnectionState = [CONNECTED]
I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: initPlayout(sampleRate=48000, channels=1)
I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: byteBuffer.capacity: 960
I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize: 3848
    WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: createAudioTrackOnLollipopOrHigher
I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: nativeOutputSampleRate: 48000
I/AudioTrack-JNI: AudioTrack_setup for usage=2 content=1 flags=0x0x800 tags=
I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: AudioTrack: session ID: 305, channels: 1, sample rate: 48000, max gain: 1.0
I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: AudioTrack: buffer size in frames: 3848
    WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: AudioTrack: buffer capacity in frames: 3848
I/org.webrtc.Logging: VolumeLogger: start@[name=worker_thread - 23606, id=18331]
V/AudioManager: getMode...
I/org.webrtc.Logging: VolumeLogger: audio mode is: MODE_NORMAL
V/AudioManager: getStreamMaxVolume  treamType: 2
    getStreamMaxVolume  treamType: 0
V/AudioManager: getMode...
I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: startPlayout
V/PlayerBase: baseStart() piid=391
D/android.media.AudioTrack: [HSM] AudioTrace play() uid: 10240, pid: 22933
I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: AudioTrackThread@[name=AudioTrackJavaThread, id=18345]
D/CustomMessageHandler: Received message{"messagePayload":"eyJjYW5kaWRhdGUiOiJjYW5kaWRhdGU6MiAxIHVkcCAxNjc3NzIxNSAxOC4yMzYuMTYyLjE0NSA1ODUyOSB0eXAgcmVsYXkgcmFkZHIgMC4wLjAuMCBycG9ydCAwIGdlbmVyYXRpb24gMCBuZXR3b3JrLWNvc3QgOTk5Iiwic2RwTWlkIjoiMCIsInNkcE1MaW5lSW5kZXgiOjB9","messageType":"ICE_CANDIDATE"}
    Ice Candidate received: SenderClientId=null
D/CustomMessageHandler: {"candidate":"candidate:2 1 udp 16777215 18.236.162.145 58529 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 network-cost 999","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0}
D/KVSWebRtcActivity: Received IceCandidate from remote 
D/KVSWebRtcActivity: Peer connection found already
D/KVSWebRtcActivity: Added ice candidate 0:0:candidate:2 1 udp 16777215 18.236.162.145 58529 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 network-cost 999: Successfully
A/m.sercomm.s1ap: thread-inl.h:269] Transitioning to runnable with checkpoint flag,  flags=58403 state=2
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x753b600000 in tid 23629 (AudioTrackJavaT), pid 22933 (m.sercomm.s1app)
E/RtgSchedManager: endActivityTransaction: margin state not match
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:53093', transport: 'socket'
```

The main error Info is:

```
E/KinesisVideoSdpObserver: onSetFailure(): Error=Failed to set remote answer sdp: Failed to set remote video description send parameters.
```

What I'm confused is that in sdp offer, the codec be like:

```
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
```

But in sdp answer I found:

```
a=rtpmap:0 H264/90000
```

Is this the main cause of the crash? On other smartphone(I tried Xiaomi, Samsung, Vivo),this two sdp lines are both H264. But HUAWEI do support H264, this is my HUAWEI Mate 20 codecInfo:

```
    E/MediaCodecList, name:: c2.android.aac.decoder,type:audio/mp4a-latm
    OMX.google.aac.decoder,type:audio/mp4a-latm
    c2.android.aac.encoder,type:audio/mp4a-latm
    OMX.google.aac.encoder,type:audio/mp4a-latm
    c2.android.amrnb.decoder,type:audio/3gpp
E/MediaCodecList, name:: OMX.google.amrnb.decoder,type:audio/3gpp
    c2.android.amrnb.encoder,type:audio/3gpp
    OMX.google.amrnb.encoder,type:audio/3gpp
    c2.android.amrwb.decoder,type:audio/amr-wb
    OMX.google.amrwb.decoder,type:audio/amr-wb
    c2.android.amrwb.encoder,type:audio/amr-wb
    OMX.google.amrwb.encoder,type:audio/amr-wb
    c2.android.flac.decoder,type:audio/flac
    OMX.google.flac.decoder,type:audio/flac
    c2.android.flac.encoder,type:audio/flac
    OMX.google.flac.encoder,type:audio/flac
    c2.android.g711.alaw.decoder,type:audio/g711-alaw
    OMX.google.g711.alaw.decoder,type:audio/g711-alaw
    c2.android.g711.mlaw.decoder,type:audio/g711-mlaw
    OMX.google.g711.mlaw.decoder,type:audio/g711-mlaw
    c2.android.gsm.decoder,type:audio/gsm
E/MediaCodecList, name:: OMX.google.gsm.decoder,type:audio/gsm
    c2.android.mp3.decoder,type:audio/mpeg
    OMX.google.mp3.decoder,type:audio/mpeg
    c2.android.opus.decoder,type:audio/opus
    OMX.google.opus.decoder,type:audio/opus
    c2.android.opus.encoder,type:audio/opus
    c2.android.raw.decoder,type:audio/raw
    OMX.google.raw.decoder,type:audio/raw
    c2.android.vorbis.decoder,type:audio/vorbis
    OMX.google.vorbis.decoder,type:audio/vorbis
    OMX.dolby.ac3.decoder,type:audio/ac3
    OMX.dolby.ac4.decoder,type:audio/ac4
    OMX.dolby.eac3.decoder,type:audio/eac3
    OMX.dolby.eac3_joc.decoder,type:audio/eac3-joc
    OMX.hisi.video.decoder.avc,type:video/avc
    OMX.hisi.video.decoder.hevc,type:video/hevc
    OMX.hisi.video.decoder.mpeg2,type:video/mpeg2
    OMX.hisi.video.decoder.mpeg4,type:video/mp4v-es
    OMX.hisi.video.decoder.vp8,type:video/x-vnd.on2.vp8
    OMX.hisi.video.decoder.vp9,type:video/x-vnd.on2.vp9
E/MediaCodecList, name:: OMX.hisi.video.encoder.avc,type:video/avc
    OMX.hisi.video.encoder.hevc,type:video/hevc
    c2.android.av1.decoder,type:video/av01
    c2.android.avc.decoder,type:video/avc
    OMX.google.h264.decoder,type:video/avc
    c2.android.avc.encoder,type:video/avc
    OMX.google.h264.encoder,type:video/avc
    c2.android.h263.decoder,type:video/3gpp
    OMX.google.h263.decoder,type:video/3gpp
    c2.android.h263.encoder,type:video/3gpp
    OMX.google.h263.encoder,type:video/3gpp
    c2.android.hevc.decoder,type:video/hevc
    OMX.google.hevc.decoder,type:video/hevc
    c2.android.hevc.encoder,type:video/hevc
    c2.android.mpeg4.decoder,type:video/mp4v-es
    OMX.google.mpeg4.decoder,type:video/mp4v-es
    c2.android.mpeg4.encoder,type:video/mp4v-es
    OMX.google.mpeg4.encoder,type:video/mp4v-es
    c2.android.vp8.decoder,type:video/x-vnd.on2.vp8
E/MediaCodecList, name:: OMX.google.vp8.decoder,type:video/x-vnd.on2.vp8
    c2.android.vp8.encoder,type:video/x-vnd.on2.vp8
    OMX.google.vp8.encoder,type:video/x-vnd.on2.vp8
    c2.android.vp9.decoder,type:video/x-vnd.on2.vp9
    OMX.google.vp9.decoder,type:video/x-vnd.on2.vp9
    c2.android.vp9.encoder,type:video/x-vnd.on2.vp9
    OMX.google.vp9.encoder,type:video/x-vnd.on2.vp9
```

And I also try to read webrtc code, I found this in MediaCodecVideoDecoderFactory:

```
private boolean isH264HighProfileSupported(MediaCodecInfo info) {
String name = info.getName();
if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 && name.startsWith("OMX.qcom.")) {
    return true;
} else {
    return VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && name.startsWith("OMX.Exynos.");
}
```

}

I doubt webrtc did not support codec like OMX.google.xxxxx . But I can't modify this code, how can I modify it so I can have a verification.

By the way, this is my webrtc implementation in gradle, if it helps:

```
implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.28513'
```

The AWS webrtc code is from AWS webrtc demo App, you can get here:[awswebrtcdemoapp](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-android.git)

And I'm sorry I can not offer my source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebRTC Android only support qcom and Exynos hardware H264 encoders, you can change isHardwareSupportedInCurrentSdkH264 in [HardwareVideoEncoderFactory](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/main/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/HardwareVideoEncoderFactory.java#227) to support other platforms such as OMX.hisi, OMX.MTK.

And then build the WebRTC to use libwebrtc.jar and libjingle_peerconnection_so.so in your project instead of

```
implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.28513'
```

how to download and build WebRTC Android:
https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/android/

Comment: That is the cause, but I use droidassist to modify the webrtc source code to support OMX.hisi. Thank you for your advice.